# Reboot machine on robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to reboot a linux machine as part my test, but after the reboot the ssh connection is closed and the test fails.

I am using the SSHLibrary to connect to my machines (all linux vms),
and I can switch the connection to this machine and than send reboot command.
The problem is when i am trying to connect the machine after the reboot because the ssh connection is closed.

```
RebootMachine
    Log To Console    Rebooting machine
    Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Start Command    reboot    true
    Sleep   45s
    Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Start Command    echo check
```

On the last line of the keyword i get: "SSHException: SSH session not active"

I tried to close the connection and reopen it like this:

```
 RebootMachine
    Log To Console    Rebooting machine
    Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Start Command    reboot    true
    Sleep   45s
    Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Close Connection
    Open Connection    ${MACHINE_IP}    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
    Start Command    echo check
```

But it switches to other machine from my connections (the echo command is executed on another machine).

I need a way to make reboot during the test and connect again to the rebooted machine, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the machine has been rebooted, the session will become inactive, later after it's up again, you must do `Open Connection` again but it seems you did `switch connection` instead after the reboot.

Try change the order of your scripts like below & I have added a few lines to login to this server:

```
Switch Connection    ${MACHINE_ALIAS}
Start Command    reboot    true
Sleep   45s

Open Connection    ${MACHINE_IP}    alias=${MACHINE_ALIAS}  prompt=$
${std_output}=  Login   ${username} ${password}
Should Contain  ${std_output}   $   

${stdout}= Execute Command  echo 'check'
 Should Contain   ${stdout}   check
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, I would suggest to remove the `Sleep    45s` from your code. A reboot might take longer time to finish and in that case your `Open Connection` would fail. In a similar scenario I have used the [`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) keyword from the BuiltIn library the get rid of the `Sleep`.

This example would wait for a maximum of three minutes and would try to open SSH connection in every 15th seconds.

```python
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     3min   15s    Open Connection    ${MACHINE_IP}    alias=${MACHINE_ALIAS}  prompt=$
```

So if your restart takes 45 seconds it will wait approximately that much time but if for some reason it takes longer in an acceptable interval, it still would work.

I would still use this solution if the 45 seconds is a requirement for the maximum reboot time, then `3min` should be replace to `45s` and the `retry_interval` (15s) could be 10 seconds or something.

Comment: but according to the documentation keyword timeout are not caught, and if the machine is still not up, the "Open Connection" fails because of timeout

Comment: @Ofir That is the point, `Open Connection` will fail a couple of times while your machine is restarting but you do not want those timeouts to be considered as failure, because the machine is restarting. This line and the test will fail if the 3 mins timeout of the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` runs off, which means your machine failed to restart under 3 mins.